# no image received error in rviz

Tags: rviz, gscam, camera, ar-pose, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS hydro . Currently ,i am stuck with a error in rviz which states that " no image received"  in status field under camera. I am using iball usb_cam.
I tried all the camera drivers like gscam,uvc_camera,usb_cam . But , this error still exists .
[Note: The image window does not produce any error. but camera window only produce this error .]
Please give me any suggestions,
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228743/no-image-received-error-in-rviz/) by [Ajith kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26236/ajith-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-10**:
Can you see the image with `image_view`?

**Comment by [Ajith kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26236/ajith-kumar/) on 2016-03-10**:
yes , i can see image with image_view

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2017-06-28**:
I had the same problem. I was publishing the image and the camera_info correctly, but the image would still not show up. Solution: republishing my static tfs at 10 Hz, using tf instead of using tf2_ros. This solved the issue. I think that similar problems are common with rviz in ROS Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two days ago, i meet this problem too. And below is how i solved it :

1, using rosconsole to open rviz node debugging mode.

```
rosconsole set /rviz_1492690688381763966 ros.rviz.message_filter debug
```

*rviz_1492690688381763966* was your rviz node's name

and it shown the messages came from your camera with the frame name was `head_camera`(i used `[usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam)` driver)

2, modify `map` to `head_camera` in **Fixed Frame** field of rviz.

---

Originally posted by [gimcuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30094/gimcuan/) with karma: 26 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skoushan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32030/skoushan/) on 2017-09-26**:
instead of changing the global frame, you could also provide `tf` data between the global frame and the camera frame (described [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/240705/rviz-how-to-show-video-from-cam-in-camera-but-not-image/))